# Spring not finding jars that are in Maven dependecy

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am developing a web app and getting the error in my Sercurity Context file:
 Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Error occured processing XML 'javax/servlet/Filter'. See Error Log for more details
    - The classes from the spring-security-web jar (or one of its dependencies) are not available. You need these to use 
     : javax.servlet.Filter

Can anyone help resolve it.  I have posted the file, POM, and web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="John" authorities="admin"
                password="letmein" />
            <security:user name="Zog" authorities="admin"
                password="iamzog" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:http use-expressions="true">  //this is where the error shows

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createoffer" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/docreate" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/offercreated" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/Home" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/newaccount" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createaccount" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/accountcreated" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/offers" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
</security:http>
```

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Mic</groupId>
<artifactId>Mic</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.31</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
 xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"   
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>spring-tutorial-50</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>accounts</display-name>
<servlet-name>accounts</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<description>Spring Database</description>
<resource-ref>
<description>DB Connection</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/sgc</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
    classpath: com/Mic/config/dao-context.xml
    classpath: com/Mic/config/service-context.xml
    classpath: com/Mic/config/security-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
`display-name>springSecurityFilterChain</display-name>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: you need to add `servlet-api` to your `pom.xml`

Comment: Added in the servlet which got rid of the error so thanks!  It opened up a bunch of other errors though but i'll try to figure them out or post another question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making use Servlet api but in your pom.xml this is no entry for servlet-api.jar. Add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

in the pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this dependency to your project.
    
        javax.servlet
        servlet-api
        3.0
        provided

Answer (score 0):

Just add `Tomcat` in your projects `Targeted Runtime`. That should do it.